# What does the term cascade refer to in syntax?

Tags: syntax, terminology

In Uriagereka's 1999 article, Multiple Spell-out, the term cascade is used in several places. I just conjecture its meaning but don't get exact one. What does a cascade mean in syntax.

Comment: It would help if you quote one or two sentences or paragraphs for context.

Comment: Yes. It's not a term used much in syntax any more; it doesn't sound very minimalist. In any event, it's a recursive phenomenon with a temporal sequence and usually positive feedback builtin.

Comment: I use the term "cascade" as a metaphorical description  of head-intitial structures. Head-initial structures "cascade" down toward the right (in left-to-right processing). Perhaps Uriagereka is using it in a similar way, i.e. as a sort of metaphor to describe the structures he is looking at.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it is **a derivational cascade**. I think it's [Juan Uriagereka](http://ling.umd.edu/people/person/juan-uriagereka/)'s terminology. Uriagereka 2005 writes that command units (or CU's, objects formed by the continuous application of Merge to the same object) are spelled-out at the end of each derivational cascade. The more common term in the Minimalist Program is **a phase**.